# Which is the needed operation for get featured products with Magento SOAP service API?

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I am trying to fetch via [Magento API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html) with [SOAP v2 service](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html#Introduction-SOAPAPIVersionv2) through WSDL in midomain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl but I don't know the exact operation to fetch the data

I am trying to get "Featured Products" with [catalogProductGetSpecialPrice](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.getSpecialPrice.html) that it is wrong

Edit: I am trying too thinking as featured products are only a product attibute, I can search all the products with attribute "featured_product", so using the attribute_id for the feature_product it could be fetched via [product_attribute.list](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttribute/product_attribute.list.html) operation

Comment: catalog_product.getSpecialPrice is for SOAP V1. catalogProductGetSpecialPrice for SOAP V2

Comment: Yes it was a mistake, updated the question and I add more info. What should I use then for fetch the featured products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ask to experienced magento developers in #magento IRC channel and for fetch 'featured products' and determine what products are featured
they said that it is needed know what makes a product as "featured" for search for it and it depends mostly in which is code as functionality of the theme.

In most themes the 'featured products' are just a specific category. So, I just need know the specific ID category

Most themes that offer a featured product block or slider allow you to determine the category in the widget/cms block.

Pulling the category_id it is possible fetch all featured products. For that the operation I use [catalogCategoryInfo](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogCategory/catalog_category.info.html) (SOAP V2) fetching all the data.

Comment: Hi, I want same thing..(featured items) so it's all related about category, right?